# In SQL, group by in INT ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have following sql table;

I need to group rows by intx value however, this intx values is dynamic 
so, there is no specific range of values.

```
id, intx,   name
"1" "70"    "x7"
"2" "99"    "x100"
"3" "100"   "x100"
"4" "101"   "x100"
"5" "69"    "x7"
"6" "50"    "x5"
```

I want to group this table with use intx.

But, I want to group values of intx between of (intx+1) and (intx-1)

forexample;
intx value = 100, 101 and 99 must be one group.

use following commands;

```
select  a.intx, b.intx,a.name,b.name,MAX(a.intx,b.intx),MIN(a.intx,b.intx)
from t1 a inner join t1 b
on a.intx  <=b.intx+1 and a.intx >= b.intx-1 and a.intx<>b.intx
group by  MAX(a.intx,b.intx)
```

but give me following result ;
a.intx, b.intx, a.name, b.name, MAX, MIN

```
a.intx  b.intx  a.name  b.name  MAX     MIN
"69"    "70"    "x7"    "x7"    "70"    "69"
"100"   "99"    "x100"  "x100"  "100"   "99"
"101"   "100"   "x100"  "x100"  "101"   "100"
```

didn't put 101 into the second group.

Comment: How do we know whether 99 belongs in the 99 group, the 100 group or the 98 group?

Comment: Wild guess: The group should then be 97-101

Comment: if value is 99 ==> intx-1, intx, intx+1 = 99, 98 and 100 in same group. so there is between of intx+1 and intx-1.

Comment: But previously you said that 99, 100 and 101 are in the same group. Do you see the problem yet?

Comment: yes, data is dynamic but will not conflict in dataset. only need to intx-1 , intx and intx+1 in same group. so if there is 99,100 and 101 in dataset, not include 98

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help feeling there is something missing from this question so in an attempt to clarify here's what happens if you apply the rule to the data provided.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (id int, intx int,   name varchar(10));
insert into t values
(1, 70  ,  'x7'),
(2, 99  ,  'x100'),
(3, 100 ,  'x100'),
(4, 101 ,  'x100'),
(5, 69  ,  'x7'),
(6, 50  ,  'x5');

select t1.intx midintx,t1.name,t3.name,t1.intx as minintx, t3.intx as maxintx from t t1
join  t t2 on t2.intx = t1.intx - 1
join  t t3 on t3.intx = t1.intx + 1;

+---------+------+------+---------+---------+
| midintx | name | name | minintx | maxintx |
+---------+------+------+---------+---------+
|     100 | x100 | x100 |     100 |     101 |
+---------+------+------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note that only x100 appears , x7 an x5 are dropped because they don't have 3 values.

If 98 does appear under x100 then

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (id int, intx int,   name varchar(10));
insert into t values
(1, 70  ,  'x7'),
(2, 99  ,  'x100'),
(3, 100 ,  'x100'),
(4, 101 ,  'x100'),
(5, 69  ,  'x7'),
(6, 50  ,  'x5'),
(7, 98  ,  'x100');

+---------+------+------+---------+---------+
| midintx | name | name | minintx | maxintx |
+---------+------+------+---------+---------+
|      99 | x100 | x100 |      99 |     100 |
|     100 | x100 | x100 |     100 |     101 |
+---------+------+------+---------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Looks right according to the rule. 
Comments please.